# Clearing all fields on a form with a master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

i am trying to clear a form on a button click, here is where i am now:

```
     ContentPlaceHolder mpContentPlaceHolder;
        mpContentPlaceHolder =
   (ContentPlaceHolder)Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1");

        foreach (Control ctrl in mpContentPlaceHolder.Controls)
        {
            lblMessageX.Text = ctrl.ToString();
            if (ctrl is TextBox)
                ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = string.Empty;
            else if (ctrl is DropDownList)
                ((DropDownList)ctrl).ClearSelection();
        }
```

it only loops once, and finds: System.Web.UI.LiteralControl

is it not searching in the right place?

my mock up looks something like:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
 <asp:Accordion   
    ID="Accordion1"   
    CssClass="accordion"  
    HeaderCssClass="accordionHeader"  
    HeaderSelectedCssClass="accordionHeaderSelected"  
    ContentCssClass="accordionContent"   
    runat="server">  

<Panes >
<asp:AccordionPane runat="server" >
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOrg" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="true" CssClass="myinputstyle"
                   OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlOrg_SelectedIndexChanged" />  
      <asp:TextBox ID="txtCase" runat="server" CssClass="myinputstyleS" MaxLength="8" />  
//and so on and so forth
```

Comment: when in the life cycle is this being called?

Comment: what do you mean? when i click the button...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to do a recursive search to get all of the controls on the page because not all controls are right under the ContentPlaceHolder.  Rather, it contains some controls that themselves contain other controls.

```
Content Place Holder
-->LiteralControl
   -->Other Control 1
   -->Other Control 2
   -->Other Control 3
      -->Maybe another level 1
      -->Maybe another level 2
   -->Other Control 4
```

LiteralControl.Controls would return "Other Control 1" through 4, but not "Maybe another level 1" or "Maybe another level 2".  To get those, you would need to call "Other Control 3".Controls

Poke around in the debugger to see the exact hierarchy.